# Display special characters returned from mySQL in drop down select box

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display utf8 characters in a drop down box which is pulled from mySQL (utf8_general_ci) the characters are returning as diamonds with a ? in the middle on.

I have tried htmlspecialchars and htmlentities. And it returns a blank string.
Site also has the charset set to utf-8.

Thank you very much.

Comment: make sure your document's head has `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Do you have this header?  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function and see if it works.

Comment: @NullPointer, sorry I am not the OP here, to accept the answer. Hope you have noticed that now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$inn_qu=mysql_query("select * from catagory where ct_id='$id' order by c_id");
      while($re=mysql_fetch_array($inn_qu)){
          $trs=get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
          $str=$re['c_rate'];
          $encode=strtr($str,$trs)
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the server's character set:

```
mysql> SET character_set_database = 'utf8mb4';
mysql> SET character_set_server = 'utf8mb4';
```

To view all MySQL variables relating to character sets:

---

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character_set%';
```

---

To change character set in [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) application:

```
/* change character set to utf8mb4 */
if (!($mysqli->[set_charset][1]("utf8mb4")))
{
    printf("Error loading character set utf8mb4: %s\n", $mysqli->error);

    exit();
}
else
{
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
```

REFERENCE:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207437/cant-set-up-unicode-support
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php